Test Quarkus extension against native build
I've created an extension that registers a list of classes for reflection (instead of adding them with the @RegisterForReflection annotation).
A couple of problems:

The classes that require registration can change in the future as they are a list of Protos and we can add new messages
The classes that need registration are nested classes as they are automatically generated by protoc
It looks like there's no way to register a whole package automatically, we have to list each individual class

The tests can call the com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat.printer().print() which goes through the list of fields using reflection and caused the issue in the first place - so if it fails it means that there are missing classes.
But is there a way to test the native executable from the extension?

"But is there a way to test the native executable from the extension?" - Yes. We do it for example in the quarkus-artemis extension (github.com) (and I think almost every other quarkiverse extension does something similar).

Brilliant. Thank you @Turing85 I'll have a look!
